# Amazon DynamoDB + Rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb

I m kinda new to DynamoDB, i need to do the following.

1. Tickets get created from bunch of places( we are storing them in Mysql).
2. Each ticket has N activities and N varies for each Ticket.
3. We are planning to store ticket activities in dynamoDB for faster retrieval.

   The following is my plan to store in dynamodb (read as Key => value)

   1. Activity id(UUID that i ll generate) => Activity data
   2. Each ticket(Ticket id from my RDBMS) => array of Activity ids..

So, i can query like, show me all activity for a ticket.

Now the real problem i have is..

How about handling permissions in it? For eg: There can be users who has access to view only their ticket's activities, or there can be users who can view all activities of any tickets..

How and where can i store that data in dynamo? Any help will be appreciated.

Any other type of storage in dynamo is also deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the UUID is cryptographic, then the user can't guess (and therefore can't query) ticket activities of other users.

This is if you don't have any validation in the application level <- which usually isn't the case.

The database is usually queried by the application with a query that was built after validating a user. The application is a super-user (admin), it can get whatever it wants from the dynamodb, but the query itself needs to be authenticated in the application level.

DynamoDb doesn't have a per item authentication. You need to figure it out in your app.

You can continue using your MySQL solution for user details, and for instance a (crypto) hash of the user can be a key in the DynamoDb.

You can also move the user details configuration to another table in DynamoDb - but that's a bit too broad and specific to cover (unless you have a specific question).

Comment: Thanks Chen.. How about the querying capabililty of DynamoDB? Suppose i have many attributes for activities(say, ticketid, person who did it, created_at etc...). Can i query based on one or combination of 2 or 3 attributes?? Is that allowed? Any links to look up? I have read about LSI. But can i query like
1. Give me all activities for a ticket(given ticket id)
2. Give me recent activities for past 2 mins(say)
3. Give me all activities